Статус битовых полей в системе категории выражений языка Си++
Данная статья содержит следующе утверждения

Битовые поля – удобный инструмент для низкоуровнего программирования,
однако, их реализация несколько выпадает из общей структуры категорий
выражений.


В то же время, взять адрес битового поля или инициализировать им
неконстантную ссылку не получится.

В моем понимании, второе утверждение верно, если уточнить что понятие адреса в взято в том же смысле как его использует стандарт. Первое не совсем. О чем я и написал комментарий:
Когда речь идет об identity,имеется в виду любой вид уникальности.
В Си++ ставится различие между storage (область памяти) и memory location (ячейка памяти).Ряд объектов обладает и тем и другим, например, объекты скалярного типа или члены классов и элементы массивов этого типа. У класса есть область памяти, но нет ячейки, в то время как члены могут занимать ячейки. У ссылок в составе классов и у битовых полей (которые по определению являются членами класса) есть ячейка памяти, но нет области памяти. Уникальной особенностью битовых полей является то, что несколько полей ненулевого размера могут занимать одну ячейку
Скорее в уникальную ситуацию можно было бы записать члены объединения, т.к. тут перекрываются области памяти. Однако нам категорически запрещено рассматривать объединение как два или более объектов существующих одновременно. И это как раз из-за того, что система категорий фундаментальна.
Указатель и ссылка обращаются к области памяти. Поэтому для битовых полей их и не может быть. Поэтому невозможна ссылка на ссылку. Однако ВСЯ ячейка памяти целиком является субъектом выражения, поэтому, если а и b - битовые поля с общей ячейкой, то результат выражения a++ + ++b является таким же неопределенным поведением как и a++ + ++a , где одно и то же значение (одна и та же ячейка) меняется дважды.
В итоге битовые поля не выбиваются из системы категорий, а являются примером того, для чего она нужна.
Верно ли мое рассуждение с точке  зрения стандарта?

Похоже, EWD был прав -- "C++ damages the brain …" и основные проблемы возникают когда крестовые абстракции начинают отображаться на конкретные структуры вычислительной системы. Что тут точно верно, так это утверждение, что у битового поля не может быть традиционного (переменная, содержащая указатель или ссылку) адреса.

@avp  Проблема не в конкретной вычислительной системе а в требованиях к интерфейсу к нему. Битовые поля или объединения не отражают возможности системы, а наоборот, ограничивпют ее возможности. А про мозг - это верно для работы с любыми документаами требующими определенности по Тьюрингу. Адвокаты и физики-квантовики туда же

@avp Будучи физиком-ядерщиком со вторым юридическим образованием, я унаследовал все три интерфейса

Когда lvalue было тем, что может быть слева, а rvalue тем, что справа, все было всем интуитивно понятно (да и люди тогда еще программировали машины для решения задачи, а сейчас, как вы верно подметили, все больше ограничивают ее использование в угоду языковым абстракциям (скоро мы конструировать компы будем не для реальных задач, а для реализации абстракций -))). И ведь  кому и для чего  реально нужны эти абстракции типа glvalue, xvalue, prvalue? (наверное чтобы разные компайлерописатели могли договориться, а манагеры удачно продавали compatibility)

@avp это деление меня всегда напрягало, потому как левые могут быть справа а часть правых обладало свойствами левых.  На самом деле тут тепер деление на четыре, вон как раз по той диаграмме Кэррола, приведенной в статье

Кстати, в статье их три (на нижнем уровне) lvalue, xvalue (может выступать как левая и правая части) и rvalue. Но для чего вся эта классификация нужна программистам не понимает уже первый из комментаторов (и я с ним солидарен). А почему должно напрягать, что левые всегда могут быть справа, я не понимаю. Кстати, наверное именно из-за этого я никакого практического смысла в такой классификации не вижу. Ну, никак студенту это не поможет понять (до компиляции), что куда можно присваивать, а что нельзя

@avp В статье 4 уникальных комбинаций свойств. Граф взятый из книги 90х лет иллюстрирует 3 из 4 , четвёртый вид есть только в таблице Кэррола, где есть деление по двум столбцам. как быть с шаблонами где этап компиляции иногда слишком поздно? На самом деле да - три основные цели: написание генериков, написание компилятора и написание генераторов кода(что последнее время популярно) или стат. анализаторов.

Что-то мы все продолжаем переливать из пустого в порожнее. В вопросе вы пишете "... В итоге битовые поля не выбиваются из системы категорий, а являются примером того, для чего она нужна." "Верно ли мое рассуждение с точке зрения стандарта?". / Понятно, что в своих комментариях я выражаю сомнение в том, что она (система категорий) вообще нужна (несет практическую пользу) кому-либо. В ваших я не вижу убедительных аргументов в обратном. Поэтому  остается только ждать, может быть кто-нибудь скажет в ответе, верны ли ваши рассуждения о месте битовых полей в ней
